# Resharper reorders my path references in javascript tests

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, testing, resharper

I'm just starting to use Jasmine in Visual Studio with R#. To make it work I have to add these lines to the top of the spec file:

```
///<reference path="../jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="../jasmine/jasmine-html.js"/>
///<reference path="../jasmine/boot.js"/>
```

However, when I run the test, the file opened in the browser contains the references in the header in another order (and strange indentation):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="referenceFile?path=~/Project/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="referenceFile?path=~/Project/Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="referenceFile?path=~/Project/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
```

The problem is that `boot.js` needs to come last, otherwise it doesn't work. Is it possible to fix this? Maybe there is a workaround if this is just R# behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `ReSharperRunner.html` file to the project;
2. Hit `Copy default implementation to clipboard` here `ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | JavaScript Tests | Custom HTML harness` and paste the code to there;
3. Specify such file here `ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | JavaScript Tests | Enable custom HTML harness | Test harness file name`
4. Specify a file location in `Test harness location` combobox.

Comment: Thank you! How do you happen to know that? Is it a known bug that reference path order is changed?